# How do I use regex to return only the first 2 words ignoring punctuation?

Tags: regex

How do I write regex command that removes a comma from string and only return first two words.  For example I have following:

```
Johnston, Bill, .T
```

and I want to return:

```
Johnston Bill
```

Comment: I suggest you edit the question to include a language tag, e.g. `java`.

Comment: Sounds like a homework!!! did you have tried anything?

Comment: Need more detail. Is there a particular language you are programming with?

Comment: have tried ([A-Z])\w+  we're using a laserfiche product that has a tool allowing you to enter pattern matching.  Unsure what language it is written in.

Comment: @Nick:- Without knowing the language it is difficult to answer this as regex is language dependent.

Comment: Is this relevant, is it help for the product you're using? https://www.laserfiche.com/support/webhelp/workflow/8.3/en-us/Content/Regular%20Expressions.htm

Comment: Incomplete question, but `"(.+), (.+),"` would capture everything in front of the two commas. So depending on the structure of your data, it may give you a start. I use R, therefore `str_match(text, "(.+), (.+),")` gave me the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
$str = 'Johnston, Bill, .T';
echo preg_replace('~(\w+), (\w+).*~', '$1 $2', $str);
// returns 'Johnston Bill'
```

Comment: The language is still unknown. ;)

Comment: @RahulTripathi: I didn't read the comments under question, and forgot to see what tags the question have.

Comment: My point is that your answer will be invalid if OP is seeking the help in Java or may be C#.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression with the substring method. ".replace(/,/g,'')"

```
var str = "Johnston, Bill, .T"


str = str.replace(/,/g,'').substring(0,13);
```

output should return: Johnston Bill